# Is any regular algebraic curve in the plane union of closed curves?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

This is related to the attempt I am doing trying to prove that any polynomial lemniscate is the union of regular closed curves. Recall by the way that a polynomial lemniscate is a curve of the form $\{z\in\mathbb C: |p(z)|=K\}$, where p is a polynomial of one complex variable with complex coefficients and $K>0$.

I proved that any polynomial lemniscate is the union of regular curves defined on open intervals. However, I have no idea of how to prove that these regular curves are indeed closed.

The following picture represents a lemniscate of 8 foci (the polynomial is of degree 8). Although there is a self-intersecting component, it can be parametrized regularly.
[image]

I conjecture that something like the following could be true:

> If a bounded algebraic curve on the plane is the union of regular curves, these curves are indeed closed.

Thank you so much in advance.